# How to add auto increment id according to a group in VFP 9 and SQL Server

Tags: sql, auto-increment, foxpro

Here is the format of the table:

```
No      group   name

1       abc     a
1       xyz     c
1       xyz     d
```

Now i want it to be like,

```
No      group   name

1       abc     a
2       abc     b
3       abc     f
1       xyz     c
2       xyz     h
1       xyz     d
```

"No" should auto increment according to "group"
Thank you

Comment: I would set up an insert trigger, in which I would query the maximum `No` in the group, then changing `No` to `max+1`

Comment: Why the last one is still 1 and not 3?

Comment: I'm really sorry, that's my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use windowing function:

```
Select group, 
name, 
row_number() over (partition by group order by name) as No
from table
```

Comment: This is works for SQL server. What should I do in Foxpro to get these results in Foxpro 9.